# Set desktop icons background color Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, icons, colors, desktop-icons

I just installed Kubuntu 16.04. Still exploring, not sure how much of an improvement over 14.04 it is, but I already have one question: I always set some desktop icons for easy starting. In 14.04, I just changed the desktop icon size to 32 and they all were smaller. That doesn't seem to work in 16.04. I can manually change the size (hold -> resize), but that's kind of a hassle and it's difficult to get them all the same size. But a more pressing problem: they all have a greyish background, which looks really awful. Can I make the Icon background either transparent (preference) or set the color manually? And is there a way to resize them all?

Thanks in advance,
Stefan